# SNMP problems after moving to Centos 9.x

Tags: snmp, centos9

I recently updated my zabbix server from centos7 to 9 (Rocky linux). Not long after I started having problems with some of the 'liveness' checks that use snmp (specifically commands like: `snmpwalk -v 2c -O vqe -c omsaRO XX.XX.XX.XX 1.3.6.1.4.1.674.11000.2000.500.1.2.29.1.3`

If I send this command every 5 minutes I get a timeout on the 4th. This pattern is regular and repeating. While this is happening I can send the same command from a Centos7 host and it works fine.

The failure is limited to one or two hosts out of dozens but its v consistent.

Ive replaced all the relevant cables and most of the traffic goes through a new switch.

It seems clear that I have misconfigured something but I have no idea where. I have dozens of other Rocky 9.x hosts but only this monitoring host that uses snmp so much seems to be having problems.

Comment: If you can observe the behavior consistently, time to capture network packets on different devices (sender/receiver) so that you can dig further. No one can tell a solution before knowing the actual problem.